# Compile 32bit kernel on 64bit machine

Tags: kernel, compiling, architecture

I'm trying to compile a kernel for a 32bit single-core Intel Atom machine. Needless to say, the compile is taking inordinate amounts of time. It's been going for 2 hours and it's still only halfway through the driver modules.

Compiling a kernel on my main desktop only takes 15 minutes but it's a 64bit machine. Can I cross compile to generate a 32bit kernel package from the better machine?

Comment: Virtual machine can do it , but it will be slower

Comment: Yeah and I could dual boot, but I'm sure it's possible to compile thing for other platforms from without leaving the current environment.

Comment: That is interesting +1 ed

Answer (score 28, accepted):

While the kernel can be cross-compiled, the easiest way is to create a 32bit (i386) chroot and build it in there.

Install `ubuntu-dev-tools`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-dev-tools
```

Create an i386 chroot:

```
$ mk-sbuild --arch=i386 precise
```

(You will probably have to run that twice. The first time, it installs `schroot` etc. and sets up `mk-sbuild`)

Then enter the chroot:

```
$ schroot -c precise-i386
```

And build the kernel, as you would, normally.

Comment: Building in a chroot is exactly the preferred method as used by developers in the Ubuntu kernel team.

Comment: Those are some pretty fancy looking tools. I'll give it a shot tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Please expand on "as you would normally". I would normally follow the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile but they do not work inside a chroot - the build dies with 'fatal error: linux/compiler.h: No such file or directory'

Comment: Mounting your home folder in chroots looks like a nice addition: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SimpleSbuild#Mount_your_home_dir

Answer (score 5):

Afaik, in gcc, you can set `-m32` flag to let it compile linux sources to 32bit executables. I don't have a wide knowledge about Makefiles, but you can tweak them.

**edit:**
I wanted to add [a question from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272357/how-to-compile-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-linux-machine-with-gcc-cmake) here, in which it is told to set cflags:

```
export CFLAGS=-m32
```

And from the linux repository in **[Torvalds](https://github.com/torvalds)**' github account, I found following section on the main makefile that you may find useful, as it tells that you can set a target architecture by setting an environment variable. Read the comments, currently, these lines are from **[this file](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/f4a75d2eb7b1e2206094b901be09adb31ba63681/Makefile)**, between lines *174-196*:

```
# Cross compiling and selecting different set of gcc/bin-utils
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# When performing cross compilation for other architectures ARCH shall be set
# to the target architecture. (See arch/* for the possibilities).
# ARCH can be set during invocation of make:
# make ARCH=ia64
# Another way is to have ARCH set in the environment.
# The default ARCH is the host where make is executed.

# CROSS_COMPILE specify the prefix used for all executables used
# during compilation. Only gcc and related bin-utils executables
# are prefixed with $(CROSS_COMPILE).
# CROSS_COMPILE can be set on the command line
# make CROSS_COMPILE=ia64-linux-
# Alternatively CROSS_COMPILE can be set in the environment.
# A third alternative is to store a setting in .config so that plain
# "make" in the configured kernel build directory always uses that.
# Default value for CROSS_COMPILE is not to prefix executables
# Note: Some architectures assign CROSS_COMPILE in their arch/*/Makefile
export KBUILD_BUILDHOST := $(SUBARCH)
ARCH        ?= $(SUBARCH)
CROSS_COMPILE   ?= $(CONFIG_CROSS_COMPILE:"%"=%)

# ...
# There are more architecture related stuff beyond this line
```