# Compile AMD athlon-xp 32 bit kernel in intel 64 bit machine

Tags: ati, kernel, 64-bit, 32-bit, chroot

Can someone tell me how to compile linux 3.7 kernel for amd athlon-xp in a 64 bit intel environment through chroot? I tried setting up a chroot environment but compilation gives me error. Thanks to all.
P.S: Compiling kernel in a virtual machine takes too long.

Comment: Please post some compiler output or more info on how did you set up your chroot.

Answer (score 0):

[Compile 32bit kernel on 64bit machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27148/compile-32bit-kernel-on-64bit-machine) I followed this thread and tuned march and tuned `gcc` flags to `athlon-xp`.